# how to write distinct count query in Linq

Tags: entity-framework, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

suppose i have a following query in Sql

```
select UserID,count(distinct ip) as NumberOfIPUsed from  UserLogs 
group by UserID
```

i want this to write with Linq

Comment: any attempt you've made that you can show?. as is it's "too broad".

Answer (score 1):

Well, first you're going to want to group by `UserID`:

```
UserLogs.GroupBy(ul => ul.UserID)
```

Then you want to get the UserID and the count of distinct `ip` from that:

```
UserLogs.GroupBy(ul => ul.UserID).Select(g => new {UserID = g.Key, Count = g.Select(ul => ul.ip).Distinct().Count()})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `Distinct` function which isn't available directly in comprehension expressions, so some functional style is required:

```
var res = await (from ul in context.UserLogs
                 group ul by ul.UserId into grouped
                 select new {
                   UserId = grouped.Key,
                   Count = group.Select(x => x.ip).Distinct().Count()
                 }).ToListAsync();
```